# Counting the the number of publications citing all of a given set of publications

Tags: citations, bibliometrics, web-of-science

I would like to specify a list of publications and find out which articles cited the ones in my list.

Is there such tool?

Comment: I don't think there is one universal "the citation graph". Which dataset are you considering working on?

Comment: So your problems is eliminating duplicates but it would be fine to search for each publication separately?

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use Europe PMC API for that. It would be limited to biomedical publications though. Using this [module](https://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService#cites) you should be able to construct your query and find intersection programmatically. Alternatively you can combine the queries on the website using Boolean logic, e.g. here is a [search](https://europepmc.org/articles/PMC5792711?fromSearch=singleResult&fromQuery=CITES:24240771_med%20AND%20CITES:24036476_med%20AND%20CITES:19366696_med) for a paper citing three particular publications.

Disclaimer: I work for Europe PMC